# retrofit JSON to POJO

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit, pojo

I am new in android, and I'm usig `retrofit`.

The problem is that I can't obtain my `POJO` from request.

my request is:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/index.php")
void login(@Field("io") String command,
           @Field("lu") String userName,
           @Field("lp") String password,
           @Field("lm") String imei,
           @Field("l") int language,
           RestCallback<ModelLoginResponse> callback);
```

server JSON response is:

```
  {
    "tk": "thdoz4hwer32",
    "pn": "1",
    "lc": {
        "1": "Opel Combo",
        "3": "VW Crafter",
        "7": "Opel Vivaro"
    },
    "stg": {
        "rs": "30",
        "sml": "http://exemple.mob.ru",
        "ssl": "index.php"
    }
}

where 1,3,7 are different every time
```

and my POJO class:

```
 @Parcel
    public class ModelLoginResponse {

    @SerializedName("pn")
    private String personalNumber;

    @SerializedName("tk")
    private String token;

    //    ?????? for "lc" and "stg" 

    public void ModelResponse(String personalNumber, String token){
        this.personalNumber = personalNumber;
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getPersonalNumber() {
        return personalNumber;
    }

    public void setPersonalNumber(String personalNumber) {
        this.personalNumber = personalNumber;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
        }
    }
```

How should I complete my `ModelLoginResponse`  POJO class for obtaining full server response???

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and you probably already figured this out, but I will just post an answer here so that others might find it helpful.

For "lc" field, where the key value could be different for every response, you can use a Map data structure such as HashMap.

You can use the same Map structure for "stg" field, but if you know that the keys will be always the same, it's often better to create another POJO class for that item.

In short, your response will be something like:

```
@Parcel
public class ModelLoginResponse {
    @SerializedName("pn")
    private String personalNumber;

    @SerializedName("tk")
    private String token;

    @SerializedName("lc")
    private HashMap<String, String> lcMap;

    @SerializedName("stg")
    private StgResponse stgResponse;

    //add getters and setters if you need them.
}
```

where StgResponse will be something like:

```
public class StgResponse {
    @SerializedName("rs")
    private Integer rs;

    @SerializedName("sml")
    private String sml;

    @SerializedName("ssl")
    private String ssl;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your ModelLoginResponse class in this way:

```
@Parcel
public class ModelLoginResponse {

@SerializedName("tk")
private String token;

@SerializedName("pn")
private String personalNumber;

@SerializedName("lc")
private String[3] lc;

@SerializedName("stg")
private String[3] stg; 

public ModelResponse(){}

public String getPersonalNumber() {
    return personalNumber;
}

public void setPersonalNumber(String personalNumber) {
    this.personalNumber = personalNumber;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public void setLc(String[] lc){
    this.lc = lc;
}

public void setStg(String[] stg){
    this.stc = stg;
}

public String getLc(){
    return lc;
}

public String getStg(){
    return stg;
}
}
```

If to parse the JSON string, you use the GSON library you need only a default constructor without arguments and every "field" of the JSON string needs his corresponding attribute in the target class.

Comment: thank's for your time but your solution is not workable, for exemple I'll need to get the int value of **rs** from **stg**

Here is a inner class for **stg** using the same logic, the main problem for me is **lc** object, because **1,3,7** changes, so I can't use `@SerialisedName("tag")`

Comment: Maybe it won't work but if you define "lc" and "stg" as String[3] array and then access to the elements navigating the array.
Else another solution could be define other two classes "lc" and "stg" and using there @SerializedName("tag"), in the main class instead of "private String lc" you can try with "private Lc lc" which is a Lc object.
The second is just an idea, i've not verified it